# delay() doesn't seem to be delaying at all, when used in an event handler

Tags: arduino, esp8266

I have an Arduino sketch on my esp8266. I want to light up the built-in LED for a few seconds any time a client connects to the wifi hosted on the esp8266. The event is triggering just fine, but the `delay()` doesn't do anything -- all the log messages in that handler show up at once, and the LED just flickers once.

The `delay()` call in `setup()` works fine, though.

```cpp
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

const char *ssid = "button";
const char *password = "buttonpassword";

void onWiFiEvent(WiFiEvent_t event) {
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
    Serial.println("led on");
    delay(5000);
    Serial.println("delay over");
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
    Serial.println("led off");
}

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial.println();
    pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
    Serial.println("setup before delay");
    delay(5000);
    Serial.println("setup after delay");

    Serial.println("Setting up AP");
    WiFi.softAP(ssid, password);
    WiFi.onEvent(onWiFiEvent, WIFI_EVENT_SOFTAPMODE_STACONNECTED);
    Serial.println("AP ready");
}

void loop() {
}
```

Comment: I did solve this by just turning the LED on in the handler, recording the time, and adding code to `loop()` to turn it off after my delay passed. I would still very much like to know why the included code didn't work, though.

Answer (score 0):

It is the expected behavior. You cannot block these callbacks with delay for synchronous check due to watchdog timer (WDT). You need to do your checks asynchronously, as you denoted in the loop and with a flag.